# Is it possible to put RSA Private Keys in Azure Key Vault Certificates?

Tags: security, openssl, rsa, storage, azure-keyvault

I need to put an RSA private key into the Azure Key Vault.

I can upload it to "Secrets", but when I do this, I am warned the functionality is deprecated and I am advised to go to the "Certificates" section.

However, no matter what I've done (or tried to do -- usually with openssl) to the text file containing my RSA private yet, the Key Vault refuses to accept it.

Is it possible?
Does anyone know the correct and exact procedure to make it so?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the algorithm that you're using for the certificate.  If it doesn't work then you can always use a secret with no problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/about-keys-details#rsa-algorithms

Comment: I didn't create the certificates.  I have no idea where they originally came from, only that they are currently stored very badly.  How would I discover the algorithm?  If we can "always" use the secret, why does Azure bother to label this deprecated?

Comment: 1) On Windows, open the certificate and go into details.  It has a field called "signature algorithm"
2) Because storing a certificate as a secret used to be the main way certs were stored in Key Vault.  Key Vault then added the certificate object and it has some restrictions.  It's possible to save the entire certificate as a Base64 encoded string and and save it as a secret.

Comment: This certificate does not have fields (maybe technically it isn't a "certificate"?)  It is an RSA private key stored in a text file, which aside from lines which declare a beginning and end are an unintelligible collection of seemingly random letters and numbers.

Comment: Try uploading the RSA key into the Keys blade, not certificate.